# How can I get from Cuenca, Ecuador to Arequipa, Peru?

Tags: air-travel, planning, peru, ecuador

I'll be making the trip somewhere near the 3rd week of June. How far ahead will I be able to  book a flight?   I'm ruling out bus trips due to the enormous distance.

Also would it be better(cheaper) to fly from Guayaquil or possibly from the Peruvian side of the border?

Everything I've found so far indicates about $400.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  I've edited your question to be more in line with [FAQ](http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: Not sure how you found $400.  I just found $315 with layover in Lima.

Comment: Hi Karlson, Would you mind sharing the details about the $315? Which city is the flight departing from?

Comment: from Guayaquil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Guayaquil is a better bet for departure and the drive from Cuenca is  spectacular.**

Round trip from Guayaquil to Arequipa presently costs $321 on LAN. Keep in mind that prices fluctuate and will go up as you get closer to your travel date because the cheaper seats get used first.

Figure 2 or 3 hours drive from Cuenca to Guayaquil. For your trip, **Guayaquil-Lima-Arequipa is the route to take**. You can save about $60 if you take an extra 7 hour drive from Guayaquil to Piura but I think you would not have much savings left when you factor transport and hotel which may be needed between.

If you do it all on a single airline, there is less hassle but you have fewer choices. You may look at doing the Lima-Arequipa way on [Peruvian Airlines](http://www.peruvian.pe) but it looks like doing both with LAN is cheaper at this time.

The road from Lima to Arequipa has *some* sites to keep you busy but it is desolated and long. Figure around 12 hours excluding stops. The driving conditions are very good though along the entire Peru coast, although I have only done it both ways twice and prefer to fly one way. To get variety, once I did the northern coast (Lima-Mancora) and came back through the cordilera but that is considerably slower and with very difficult driving conditions for large segments.

Definitely Guayaquil to Lima should be a flight if you are not interested in the area. There are some gems of cultural interest, colonial towns but lots of empty space in between.